# Are round corners costly?

Tags: round, roundover

Let's suppose that I want to manufacture and sell bed frames. Instead of a plain square, I want all 4 corners to be rounded, simply for aesthetic purposes.

Would this increase the cost to manufacture this item significantly?

[image]

Comment: depends on original design, and equipment available.

Comment: @bowlturner I added a picture. Can you have a look?

Comment: @bowlturner Actually, is there is no design yet. So it's a blank slate.

Comment: I didn't think so initially but I think the answer to this has to be a plain yes. Of course 'significantly' is a bit open-ended, but it'll definitely increase costs due to *far* greater time this would take over a square one of the same initial dimensions. It's not just the diff. in shaping, but also any subsequent smoothing operations (which commercially there's a >95% likelihood would all be sanding) will take way more time. Think of it this way: the basic steps that form a square corner would all need to be done first on these, and then you add operations on top of that + more sanding time.

Comment: Oh and welcome to Woodworking BTW!

Comment: @BearBileFarmingisTorture yes, with that picture I would think it would add a bit of time, though it's a nice look and should also increase the value.  And doing this en masse, you should be able to find a process that can make them 'quickly' , such as doing 4 or 8 corners at once, and then cutting them to length.

Comment: @bowlturner, I was envisioning a bandsaw cut to do the primary shaping, which in most shops would have to be done one corner at a time. Doing a long run and cutting down to desired length is a good idea, but I'm not sure how one would do the round profiling expediently. A curved-top router jig is the only way I can think of offhand, and it's another big jig thingie to store when not in use :-)

Comment: I know this question is generating a lot of discussion but honestly I think it's too broad and out of scope for this stack.

If you wanted to ask "How could I achieve this with [list of tools] that would be in scope for this stack.

Answer (score 7):

Whether the added cost is "significant" depends a lot on how much the balance of the design costs. More directly, however, the rounded corner will probably add a couple of hours of labor plus material costs. Unlike the previous two posts, I don't see that you will be able to cut these from solid stock, at least for a radius similar to that shown in the photo. It will be very difficult to source stock that thick and will have very limited choices of species. A bent lamination is possible, but a radius like that shown will require thin plies, certainly ⅛" or less, which will be time consuming to produce and form. You might be able to bend a core from bending ply or kerfed plywood, then veneer.

My approach would be to make a staved quarter cylinder perhaps with extensions at the tangents. By selecting the number of segments you can control the deviation from a true cylinder, and hence how much finishing is need to get a smooth curve. If you keep your staves in order and use a thin kerf blade for the bevel cuts you can preserve the grain pattern. And you don't end up wasting huge amounts of wood. You can also use the same stock you use for the balance of the frame, which maintains a consistent look.

[image: staved construction]

Comment: To my (inexpert) eye it looks like the corner in the OP's photo is made a little like this, but from just three segments (with a piece of veneer on top to disguise the fact).

Comment: This is a great idea. My only tweak would be to make a full cylinder, spin it round on the lathe, then saw into quarters.

Answer (score 5):

Your cost is going to be roughly the cost of the wood (raw material) that is removed, combined with the time (labor cost) it takes to remove it.

The greater of the two would be the time (labor cost) in shaping the corner. Cutting the curve on all four legs at once and so forth will keep the cost to a minimum. However both of these costs are very highly dependent upon the wood you're using and the efficiency of the methods and skill of the person used to make the curve.

My guess is, using somewhat optimized methods, the general cost would not be significantly affected in a commercial production environment fully stocked with tools and experienced workers. Doing this in a small shop with limited tools could be a bit harder and require more labor for a "one-off" build.

Comment: If we assume solid wood, I think if we compare the imaginary square leg of the same dimensions with a rounded one as pictured surely the *only* real factor is the increased labour cost? Yes, obviously there's more waste, but the materials cost would be the same regardless, so there's no increase to pass on.

Comment: @Graphus You're right. It's not like that wood is going to be used for anything else. I was thinking that the wood wouldn't necessarily be wasted with square corners, but on second thought, the difference would probably be negligible.

Comment: @Graphus - what's this square leg you are comparing to? There is no leg in the photo - the rounded corner is just part of the frame. The mattress and frame are supported under the platform that the mattress lies on. A reverse image search [shows](https://www.betten-prinz.de/media/image/94/f0/7b/Hasena-Oak-Line-Modul-18jpg_600x600.jpg)  what is almost certainly the source of the detail image in the post.

Comment: @Llaves whether it's the corner of a leg or the frame, the _thought process_ described in this answer doesn't change.

Comment: What about starting with a round post, cutting it in half, and then notching each of the halves to accommodate the horizontal pieces from the sides?  The design would be a bit different from what's shown, but except for the top surface all cuts or carves would be on concealed surfaces.

Comment: @supercat I've seen something similar in solid pine from ikea, though they used hardware concealed by the mattress (and awkwardly tightened by the buyer) to pull the long side/end pieces into the notches in the round leg - no need to cut the round part in half, but the drilling would need a metal jig.

Comment: @ChrisH: I was envisioning cutting the round part in half as a means of saving material, since one only needs a quarter of the perimeter of the post.  Cutting in thirds could probably save even more material if there was a good way of doing that, but cutting in half is easier.

Comment: @supercat in that case there should be a way start with something really big, cut into quarters.  Then either glue on the straight parts of the corner piece or make a joint on the inside that's also part of the mattress or slat support, or likely both

Comment: If one started by cutting a round post into quarters, the angles between the cut edges and the round edges would be slightly less than 90 degrees because of material lost while making the cuts.  If one were starting with an unfinished post, one could use one that was slightly oversized, but I would think finishing a round post would be easier than finishing a round surface of a cut piece.

Comment: @supercat - Where will you find a round post of furniture grade dry/stable hardwood, esp in production quantities?

Comment: @Llaves: Depends on the desired diameter, but round posts for things like stairway newels didn't strike me as exotic, though perhaps they're less common than in decades past.

Comment: @Llaves, did you miss the word *imaginary*?

Comment: @Graphus - no, I didn't miss the word imaginary, which modifies square (vs. round). There is no *leg* , square or round. If the side and end of the frame were to meet in a right angle, there is no need for an additional piece ("square leg"), just a simple butt joint. So the whole notion is a red herring.

Comment: @supercat - a newel post is not particularly large. The largest round posts Home Depot offers are 3" diameter. A specialty supplier I found has 3.5" posts. The corner radius in the picture would require a substantially larger diameter post than that. Larger diameter posts, if paint grade, would be made from stacked lumber glued together. Even larger items like porch columns were made from staves glued together.

Comment: @Llaves, from the single photo provided it wasn't clear whether this was merely a corner piece or functionally a leg. But irrespective of that, my point was about supposed waste in the rounded version versus the square version, since there isn't it leaves greater workshop time as the only increase in costs.

Answer (score 3):

The bigger the sweep the more expensive it will be,

You have to cut out the corner sweep out of a larger block of wood. You might be able to nest some of the corners and save some wood that way. But then the cuts become a lot more complicated

The more straightforward solution is to not have the corners be solid wood and instead use something like bent lamination and a veneer to fake the corner being a solid bit of wood.

Comment: Surely bent laminations would just add time?

Comment: Would lamination be able to be structural part of the frame? (I'm pretty sure carved one with vertical grain can't be structural part and had to be purely a decoration)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov aren't there chairs with bent laminations for the frame/legs - I'm sure I've seen some even with quite splayed legs, so not a pure compressive load

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yes.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly cheaper solutions to achieve rounded corners than what appears in your photo. But if cheap isn't the look you’re going for the tool you want is an [automatic band saw](https://www.behringersaws.com/products/behringer-bandsaws/vertical-bandsaws/lps-automatic/lps40-160-4a.html).
[image]

No handling the work while cutting. Deals with nesting. But if you can fit this in your garage you have one heck of a garage.

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :)